# MySQL Query - Not Between Two Dates

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a query that selects all the users that have not logged in for two months (`last_access`), the `insert_date` is not within two months of today and the `status` is not 2.

The `last_access` and `insert_date` are both `datetime`.

This is the code I have;

```
SELECT * 
FROM `wp_SDzEBA_pc_users`
WHERE `last_access` NOT BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH AND NOW()
AND `insert_date` NOT BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH AND NOW()
AND `status` <> 2
```

But it seems to still select users that have logged in within a two month period.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code should work. Please provide sample data, current and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: Example date it returns in the query is `2020-10-17 10:51:00` - Maybe I need to do NOW() + 1 day somehow because there might be a difference between the Server date? @GMB

Comment: I think  `NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY` fixes the issue actually

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn’t use `between` for this. One inequality condition seems more appropriate:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `wp_SDzEBA_pc_users`
WHERE 
    `last_access` < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
    AND `insert_date` < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
    AND `status` <> 2
```

Basically this gives users that did not connect over the last two months, and that were inserted more than two months ago.

You might also want to handle users that never connected (I would assume that `last_access` would be `null` in that case):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `wp_SDzEBA_pc_users`
WHERE 
    (`last_access` IS NULL OR `last_access` < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
    AND `insert_date` < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
    AND `status` <> 2
```